# Microsoft Project 2007 question

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-project

I'm using Project 2007. I have a some problem.

1. How to set default font?
2. How to change key binding to when press enter key, insert new row?
3. What is task complete (100 percent) keyboard shortcut.
4. Is it possible to set tag to Task
5. Is it possible to set complete task can be strikeout or any gray colored.

ebattulga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1 see Microsoft Office Online - [Specify the default font cell colors and patterns for a view](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project/HA101524811033.aspx)

For #3 I think you should record a macro and assign a shortcut key for that

Answer (score 0):

For #1 I would think the Format > Text Styles menu should help. Open the text styles menu and I think you should be able to set the 'Task' font type to your choice. Haven't used Microsoft Project 2007 but I think this should work.